# App works on emulator but not on real device (Both API 23)

Tags: java, android, logcat

I have an app which i can open and execute on the emulator without having errors. But when I want to run this app on my real phone (Samsung Galaxy S6 6.0.1), the app doesn't show everything. Also there are 2 errors listed in the logcat:

```
    06-14 17:05:13.521 1251-1251/? E/Zygote: v2
    06-14 17:05:13.521 1251-1251/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD checking this for 10300
    06-14 17:05:13.521 1251-1251/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD not a persona
    06-14 17:05:13.521 1251-1251/? I/SELinux: Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram, index[1], SPD-policy is existed. and_ver=SEPF_SECMOBILE_6.0.1 ver=11
    06-14 17:05:13.521 1251-1251/? W/SELinux: Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram, index[1], priority [1], priority version is VE=SEPF_SECMOBILE_6.0.1_0011
    06-14 17:05:13.521 1251-1251/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
    06-14 17:05:13.521 1251-1251/? W/SELinux: SELinux: seapp_context_lookup: seinfo=default, level=s0:c512,c768, pkgname=com.example.alexanders916.vertretungsplan 
    06-14 17:05:13.521 1251-1251/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
    06-14 17:05:13.541 1251-1251/com.example.alexanders916.vertretungsplan D/TimaKeyStoreProvider: TimaSignature is unavailable
    06-14 17:05:13.541 1251-1251/com.example.alexanders916.vertretungsplan D/ActivityThread: Added TimaKeyStore provider
    06-14 17:05:13.561 1251-1251/com.example.alexanders916.vertretungsplan W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/com.example.alexanders916.vertretungsplan-2/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.example.alexanders916.vertretungsplan rsrc of package com.example.alexanders916.vertretungsplan
    06-14 17:05:13.561 1251-1251/com.example.alexanders916.vertretungsplan I/InjectionManager: Inside getClassLibPath + mLibMap{0=, 1=}
    06-14 17:05:13.561 1251-1251/com.example.alexanders916.vertretungsplan D/ResourcesManager: For user 0 new overlays fetched Null
    06-14 17:05:13.561 1251-1251/com.example.alexanders916.vertretungsplan I/InjectionManager: Inside getClassLibPath caller 
    06-14 17:05:13.571 1251-1251/com.example.alexanders916.vertretungsplan W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.alexanders916.vertretungsplan-2/lib/arm64
    06-14 17:05:13.571 1251-1251/com.example.alexanders916.vertretungsplan D/InjectionManager: InjectionManager
    06-14 17:05:13.571 1251-1251/com.example.alexanders916.vertretungsplan D/InjectionManager: fillFeatureStoreMap com.example.alexanders916.vertretungsplan
    06-14 17:05:13.571 1251-1251/com.example.alexanders916.vertretungsplan I/InjectionManager: Constructor com.example.alexanders916.vertretungsplan, Feature store :{}
    06-14 17:05:13.571 1251-1251/com.example.alexanders916.vertretungsplan I/InjectionManager: featureStore :{}
    06-14 17:05:13.571 1251-1251/com.example.alexanders916.vertretungsplan W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/com.example.alexanders916.vertretungsplan-2/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.example.alexanders916.vertretungsplan rsrc of package com.example.alexanders916.vertretungsplan
    06-14 17:05:13.571 1251-1251/com.example.alexanders916.vertretungsplan W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/com.example.alexanders916.vertretungsplan-2/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.example.alexanders916.vertretungsplan rsrc of package com.example.alexanders916.vertretungsplan
    06-14 17:05:13.641 1251-1251/com.example.alexanders916.vertretungsplan I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
    06-14 17:05:13.641 1251-1251/com.example.alexanders916.vertretungsplan I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
    06-14 17:05:13.801 1251-1251/com.example.alexanders916.vertretungsplan D/Activity: performCreate Call Injection manager
    06-14 17:05:13.801 1251-1251/com.example.alexanders916.vertretungsplan I/InjectionManager: dispatchOnViewCreated > Target : com.example.alexanders916.vertretungsplan.MainActivity isFragment :false
    06-14 17:05:13.811 1251-1251/com.example.alexanders916.vertretungsplan D/SecWifiDisplayUtil: Metadata value : SecSettings2
    06-14 17:05:13.811 1251-1251/com.example.alexanders916.vertretungsplan D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{879e39a I.E...... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
    06-14 17:05:13.811 1251-1277/com.example.alexanders916.vertretungsplan D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
    06-14 17:05:13.851 1251-1277/com.example.alexanders916.vertretungsplan D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLES_mali.so
    06-14 17:05:13.901 1251-1277/com.example.alexanders916.vertretungsplan D/libEGL: eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0x7fa4901178
    06-14 17:05:13.901 1251-1277/com.example.alexanders916.vertretungsplan I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
    06-14 17:05:13.911 1251-1277/com.example.alexanders916.vertretungsplan D/mali_winsys: new_window_surface returns 0x3000,  [1440x2560]-format:1
    06-14 17:05:13.921 1251-1251/com.example.alexanders916.vertretungsplan I/InjectionManager: dispatchCreateOptionsMenu :com.example.alexanders916.vertretungsplan.MainActivity
    06-14 17:05:13.921 1251-1251/com.example.alexanders916.vertretungsplan I/InjectionManager: dispatchPrepareOptionsMenu :com.example.alexanders916.vertretungsplan.MainActivity
    06-14 17:05:13.921 1251-1251/com.example.alexanders916.vertretungsplan D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) or=1
    06-14 17:05:13.931 1251-1251/com.example.alexanders916.vertretungsplan W/DisplayListCanvas: DisplayListCanvas is started on unbinded RenderNode (without mOwningView)
    06-14 17:05:13.931 1251-1277/com.example.alexanders916.vertretungsplan D/libGLESv1: DTS_GLAPI : DTS is not allowed for Package : com.example.alexanders916.vertretungsplan
    06-14 17:05:13.951 1251-1251/com.example.alexanders916.vertretungsplan I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@ff7a606 time:528865674
```

What do the 2 errors (E/Zygote:...) mean?

Code:`
    package com.example.alexanders916.vertretungsplan;

```
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
static String defaultGrade=null, line=null;
static final String MY_PREFERENCES = "VPPrefs";
static URL url;
static StringBuffer sb= new StringBuffer();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE);
    defaultGrade = sharedPreferences.getString("defaultGrade", "keine");
    defaultGrade="23";
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int day_of_week = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    int week_of_year = c.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
    int hour_of_day = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int abzug = 1;
    /************************
     Sunday = 1
     Monday = 2
     Tuesday = 3
     Wednesday = 4
     Thursday = 5
     Friday = 6
     Saturday = 7
     ************************/

    if (day_of_week == 2 || day_of_week == 3 || day_of_week == 4 || day_of_week == 5 || day_of_week == 6) {
        if (hour_of_day >= 13) day_of_week = day_of_week + abzug;
    }
    if (day_of_week == 7 || day_of_week == 1) {
        day_of_week = 2;
        week_of_year = week_of_year + abzug;
    }
    if(week_of_year==20||week_of_year==21){
        day_of_week = 2;
        week_of_year=22;
    }
    try{
        url = new URL("http://mpg-vertretungsplan.de/w/"+(week_of_year-abzug)+"/w000"+defaultGrade+".htm");
    }catch(MalformedURLException e){e.printStackTrace();}

    try{
        InputStream is = (InputStream) url.getContent();
        BufferedReader isReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        while ((line = isReader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
    }catch(IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}

    String htmlContent = null;
    htmlContent = sb.toString();
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlContent);
    htmlContent = doc.toString();
    boolean inTable = false;
    int step = 0;
    CharSequence start = "<td class=\"list\" align=\"center\">",
            end = "</td>";

    CharSequence date = null, grade = null, hours = null, subject = null, room = null, oldSubject = null, text = null;
    CharSequence mon = "Montag</b>", die = "Dienstag</b>", mit = "Mittwoch</b>", don = "Donnerstag</b>", fre = "Freitag</b>";
    StringReader strReader = new StringReader(htmlContent);
    BufferedReader cpuReader = new BufferedReader(strReader);
    String sharedDate=null;
    int intColor=1;
    TableLayout tlayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);
    tlayout.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);

    TextView textGrade = new TextView(this);
    TextView textDate;
    TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
    TableRow row1 = new TableRow(this);
    TextView text1 = new TextView(this);
    TextView text2 = new TextView(this);
    TextView text3 = new TextView(this);
    TextView text4 = new TextView(this);
    TextView text5 = new TextView(this);
    TableRow.LayoutParams marginParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    marginParams.width = 0;
    marginParams.weight = 1;
    marginParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;

    TableRow.LayoutParams marginParams2 = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    marginParams2.width = 0;
    marginParams2.weight = 1;
    marginParams2.gravity = Gravity.START;
    marginParams2.span = 1;

    getGrade();
    textGrade.setText("Klasse " + defaultGrade + "\n");
    textGrade.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    textGrade.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    textGrade.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 20);
    row1.addView(textGrade, marginParams2);
    text1.setText("Stunde");
    row.addView(text1, marginParams);
    text2.setText("Fach");
    row.addView(text2, marginParams);
    text3.setText("Raum");
    row.addView(text3, marginParams);
    text4.setText("statt");
    row.addView(text4, marginParams);
    text5.setText("Text");
    row.addView(text5, marginParams);
    tlayout.addView(row1);
    tlayout.addView(row);
    try{
        while ((line = cpuReader.readLine()) != null) {
            switch(step){
                case 8:
                    step=9;
                    row = new TableRow(this);
                    switch(intColor){
                        case 1:
                            row.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFCF9A"));
                            //row.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFE7CD"));
                            intColor=0;
                            break;
                        case 0:
                            //row.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#CDFAFF"));
                            row.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFE7CD"));
                            intColor=1;
                            break;
                    }
                    text1 = new TextView(this);
                    text1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    text2 = new TextView(this);
                    text2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    text3 = new TextView(this);
                    text3.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    text4 = new TextView(this);
                    text4.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    text5 = new TextView(this);
                    text5.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

                    text1.setText(" "+hours);
                    row.addView(text1, marginParams);
                    text2.setText(subject);
                    row.addView(text2, marginParams);
                    text3.setText(room);
                    row.addView(text3, marginParams);
                    text4.setText(oldSubject);
                    row.addView(text4, marginParams);
                    text5.setText(text);
                    text5.setMaxLines(3);
                    text5.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
                    text5.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
                    row.addView(text5, marginParams);
                    tlayout.addView(row);
            }
            if(line.contains(mon))sharedDate="\n\n"+"Montag:";
            if(line.contains(die))sharedDate="\n\n"+"Dienstag:";
            if(line.contains(mit))sharedDate="\n\n"+"Mittwoch:";
            if(line.contains(don))sharedDate="\n\n"+"Donnerstag:";
            if(line.contains(fre))sharedDate="\n\n"+"Freitag:";
            if(line.contains("</tr>"))inTable=false;
            if(inTable){
                switch(sharedDate){
                    case "\n\n"+"Montag:":
                        row = new TableRow(this);
                        textDate = new TextView(this);
                        textDate.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                        textDate.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                        textDate.setText(sharedDate);
                        row.addView(textDate);
                        tlayout.addView(row);
                        sharedDate="null";
                        intColor = 1;
                        break;
                    case "\n\n"+"Dienstag:":
                        row = new TableRow(this);
                        textDate = new TextView(this);
                        textDate.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                        textDate.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                        textDate.setText(sharedDate);
                        row.addView(textDate);
                        tlayout.addView(row);
                        sharedDate="null";
                        intColor=1;
                        break;
                    case "\n\n"+"Mittwoch:":
                        row = new TableRow(this);
                        textDate = new TextView(this);
                        textDate.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                        textDate.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                        textDate.setText(sharedDate);
                        row.addView(textDate);
                        tlayout.addView(row);
                        sharedDate="null";
                        intColor=1;
                        break;
                    case "\n\n"+"Donnerstag:":
                        row = new TableRow(this);
                        textDate = new TextView(this);
                        textDate.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                        textDate.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                        textDate.setText(sharedDate);
                        row.addView(textDate);
                        tlayout.addView(row);
                        sharedDate="null";
                        intColor=1;
                        break;
                    case "\n\n"+"Freitag:":
                        row = new TableRow(this);
                        textDate = new TextView(this);
                        textDate.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                        textDate.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                        textDate.setText(sharedDate);
                        row.addView(textDate);
                        tlayout.addView(row);
                        sharedDate="null";
                        intColor=1;
                        break;
                }
                switch(step){
                    case 1:
                        int beginIndex = line.indexOf(start.toString()) + start.length();
                        int endIndex = line.indexOf(end.toString());
                        date = line.substring(beginIndex, endIndex);
                        step=2;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        beginIndex = line.indexOf(start.toString()) + start.length();
                        endIndex = line.indexOf(end.toString());
                        grade = line.substring(beginIndex, endIndex);
                        step=3;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        beginIndex = line.indexOf(start.toString()) + start.length();
                        endIndex = line.indexOf(end.toString());
                        hours = line.substring(beginIndex, endIndex);
                        step=4;
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        beginIndex = line.indexOf(start.toString()) + start.length();
                        endIndex = line.indexOf(end.toString());
                        subject = line.substring(beginIndex, endIndex);
                        step=5;
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        beginIndex = line.indexOf(start.toString()) + start.length();
                        endIndex = line.indexOf(end.toString());
                        room = line.substring(beginIndex, endIndex);
                        step=6;
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        beginIndex = line.indexOf(start.toString()) + start.length();
                        endIndex = line.indexOf(end.toString());
                        oldSubject = line.substring(beginIndex, endIndex);
                        step=7;
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        beginIndex = line.indexOf(start.toString()) + start.length();
                        endIndex = line.indexOf(end.toString());
                        text = line.substring(beginIndex, endIndex);
                        step=8;
                        break;
                }
            }
            if(line.contains("<tr class=\"list odd\">")||line.contains("<tr class=\"list even\">")){
                inTable=true;
                step=1;
            }
            if(line.contains("</tr>"))inTable=false;
        }
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
public void getGrade(){
    switch(defaultGrade){
        case "01":
            defaultGrade="5a";
            break;
        case "02":
            defaultGrade="5b";
            break;
        case "03":
            defaultGrade="5c";
            break;
        case "04":
            defaultGrade="5d";
            break;
        case "05":
            defaultGrade="6a";
            break;
        case "06":
            defaultGrade="6b";
            break;
        case "07":
            defaultGrade="6c";
            break;
        case "08":
            defaultGrade="6d";
            break;
        case "09":
            defaultGrade="7a";
            break;
        case "10":
            defaultGrade="7b";
            break;
        case "11":
            defaultGrade="7c";
            break;
        case "12":
            defaultGrade="7d";
            break;
        case "13":
            defaultGrade="7e";
            break;
        case "14":
            defaultGrade="8a";
            break;
        case "15":
            defaultGrade="8b";
            break;
        case "16":
            defaultGrade="8c";
            break;
        case "17":
            defaultGrade="8d";
            break;
        case "18":
            defaultGrade="8e";
            break;
        case "19":
            defaultGrade="9a";
            break;
        case "20":
            defaultGrade="9b";
            break;
        case "21":
            defaultGrade="9c";
            break;
        case "22":
            defaultGrade="9d";
            break;
        case "23":
            defaultGrade="9e";
            break;
        case "24":
            defaultGrade="10a";
            break;
        case "25":
            defaultGrade="10b";
            break;
        case "26":
            defaultGrade="10c";
            break;
        case "27":
            defaultGrade="10d";
            break;
        case "28":
            defaultGrade="11";
            break;
        case "29":
            defaultGrade="12";
            break;
    }
}
```

}
`

Comment: It doesn't show everything (so something is showing) or it doesn't show anything (nothing is showing)?

Comment: On the emulator it shows everything, but on my S6 it only shows a part of the code. (I will post the code above)

Comment: The part until the while-loop works on the phone, but after this loop the phone is some kind ignoring the code

Comment: Please use an AsyncTask or some networking library. Don't disable StrictMode for HTTP requests.

Comment: @cricket_007 But what is false with the code, which you can read now? I'm new in the development of android apps, so I will work on and make my code more efficient but I just don't understand why this code works on the emulator and doesn't work on a real device

Comment: Hard to say, that is one of the difficulties of developing for Android. Each device has some variant of uniqueness to it. I'm not sure if that Zygote error really means anything special, are you sure there is no other error in that output?

Comment: Yeah, there aren't any other errors.