# Failed to install app apk in android device

Tags: android, apk

I have the app running fine in the android emulator. But when I tried to install in the device it is giving error.

In CoolPad Note - running 5.1 version - error is "Failed to install the app"
In Galaxy A7 - running 6.0 version - error is "parsing failed"

I am using sqlite db, apache csv parser lib, Square's sqldelight.

Min Sdk - 19 and Max Sdk - 25

I tried giving all the uses-permission based on this [link](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Arinerron/1bcaadc7b1cbeae77de0263f4e15156f/raw/6c577d9f425340a7dcd1ec5efc7a12c054d6623f/xml_permissions.txt)

I unlocked developer options in the phone and enabled installing from unknown sources. Still not able to install the app. In the same phone, I can install a simple android app. So the problem is with the package or the code. Please help.

Usb with both the phones are not working. So I am sending the apk through bluetooth and then installing it with package installer in the phone. How to get the installation log from the phone.

The app is 4 forms and uses fragments. If needed I can upload the apk.

Comment: Are you trying to install signed or unsigned version of app? Using ProGuard? Have you investigate if you have to make some kind of change in proguard.txt related to csv parser?

Comment: I tried both signed and unsigned, but both failed. I am using default ProGuard settings. I will look into that.

Comment: If you tried unsigned too, then it's less likely some mess with minify and proguard.txt, cause this is commonly used on signed release versions (or are you minifying debug version too?). I think it's worth to have a try in a different kind of apk transference from pc to mobile, have a try using email or even FTP just to ensure bluetooth is not corrupting in some way your apk. There are very nice and simple android FTP servers on the store and they can be very useful at your situation, i.e., without usb (sorry for you - usb misconfigured? tried MTP?).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have had a similar problem. For me the problem was the APK Signature Scheme v2 option in Android Studio (version 2.3.1):
 https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0.html#apk_signature_v2

When signing my apk with Signature version v2 selected, I was able to download and install my apk on a LG Nexus 5X (android 7.1.1). But on a Motorola Moto G3 (android 5.1) I would see "failed to install".

By selecting both signature version v1 and v2 when signing my app, this problem was resolved and I could download and install the apk on both phones.

I hope this will help you and others with the same issue.

[image]

Comment: It did worked for me by selecting both the signatures, but don't know the reason for that.

Answer (score 3):

If you use Galaxy A7.
You can tap *#9900# in dialer app (name is 'phone').
You can find "RUN DUMPSTATE/LOGCAT" and tap it.
Then tap "COPY TO SDCARD(INCLUDE CP RAMDUMP)".
You can find 'log' folder in MyFiles app.

Comment: This is good information, if true (I didn't verify). And positively can work as the correct answer to the OP, cause he stated: "How to get the installation log". Congrats.

Comment: I got the logcat dump and got this error DTS is not allowed for Package. This is similar to the question here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37815875/app-works-on-emulator-but-not-on-real-device-both-api-23). Not able to identify the error.